# buffers managed by USB controller

Tags: dual-boot, usb

I am working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTC OS, where I have connected a DSP which supports USB 3.0.

My system configuration Memory 3.6GiB
Processor Intel® Core™ i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4
Grpahics Intel® Haswell Desktop 
Os type 64-bit
Disk 309.6 GB

Ubuntu is just a partition and I have windows 7 installed in other partition.

I want to know how much is the buffer size managed by USB controller? Am I able to change the buffer size? The other devices connected to USB 2.0 are a keyboard and mouse and nothing else to USB 3.0.

Also, quite often my system (while using Ubuntu OS)m hangs and the orange LED is turned ON (not blinking). Why is this? How can I avoid it?

Thanking you
Rensi